# How to expose Redis port in DDEV?

Tags: redis, ddev

I'm using DDEV v1.22.6 with the [ddev-redis](https://github.com/ddev/ddev-redis) service. How can I expose the Redis port? I'd like to connect to Redis in the RedisInsight app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expose a non-http port (I think redis is non-http) try using the `ports` key in the `docker-compose.redis_extra.yaml` override file. Expose the port you want with `ports` and see how it goes. Unfortunately, the port will need to be different for each project, or you'll have conflicts over it.

For example, your docker-compose.redis_extra.yaml might have

```
services:
  redis:
    ports:
    - 6379:6379
```

But you might want to try using redis-commander instead, which is running inside the docker network and doesn't have to have the redis port exposed to the outer network. https://github.com/ddev/ddev-redis-commander